# Teechart chart Data issue

Tags: activex, teechart

I charting control we round off the data say if you have data as 1.3456 it is rounded off to 1.345 can we extend the digit after the decimal to 4 or 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use valueformat property for controlling decimal places

chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetLabels().SetValueFormat("0.0000") //for 4 decimal places
chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetLabels().SetValueFormat("0.00000")//for  5 decimal places
similerly for bottom axis as well.